# Get consecutive elements in an array object

Tags: javascript

example:
I have an array of objects:

```
a= [
{description: 'H', order: 1},

{description: 'K', order: 2},

{description: 'K', order: 3},

{description: 'H', order: 4}, //I want choose this

{description: 'e', order: 5}, //I want choose this

{description: 'l', order: 6}, //I want choose this

{description: 'l', order: 7}, //I want choose this

{description: 'o', order: 8}, //I want choose this

{description: 'e', order: 9},

{description: 'l', order: 10}

]
```

I want to filter and find 5 object elements next by next ( that are appearing in a sequence/order in the given array), my expectation is:

```
b = [

{description: 'H', order: 4},

{description: 'e', order: 5}, 

{description: 'l', order: 6},

{description: 'l', order: 7},

{description: 'o', order: 8}
]
```

Thank u everyone

Comment: Please provide more info - like how do you want to check/filter the objects, etc.

Comment: I want filter array a => a new array b

Comment: Yes, you already said that, what have you tried? You should create a [mcve] of what you tried

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, this is the first time I ask a question in here. I don't know to do  that. I tried it before but not successful

Comment: @VuLe yeah, but what are the "conditions" for filtering?

Comment: @IamL I need filter with key ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] and get object elements contain it

Comment: @IamL I just want to get the sequence  objects and start with "H" order:4

Comment: `a.filter(arr=> ['H', 'e', 'l', 'o'].includes(arr.description));` should do the trick

Comment: ^^ check this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with the time complexity of `O(n)`

```js
const arr = [
    { description: 'H', order: 1 },
    { description: 'K', order: 2 },
    { description: 'K', order: 3 },
    { description: 'H', order: 4 },
    { description: 'e', order: 5 },
    { description: 'l', order: 6 },
    { description: 'l', order: 7 },
    { description: 'o', order: 8 },
    { description: 'e', order: 9 },
    { description: 'l', order: 10 }
];

const key = 'Hello';

// result array
const result = [];

// current index of the test
let index = 0;

for (let e of arr) {
    // if matches the test, add the element to the result array and increse the index
    if (e.description === key[index]) {
        result.push(e);
        index++;
        
        // if already found the result, stop the iteration
        if (index >= key.length) break;
    } else {  // if failed the test, clear the index and the result
        index = 0;
        result.length = 0;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: in the case: `key = 'He llo'` or  `key='Hell o'`, it's not work?

Comment: I want to cover all case with key include `" "`

Comment: It will not, but it's better to make it an array: `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`

Comment: You can always do `key = key.replace(/\s/g, '')` to get rid of the empty spaces

Comment: the "H" you got is `order:1`, but I want to get the `order: 4` which  appearing in a sequence in the given array

Comment: @VuLe I'm not sure what are you talking about. The solution gives the exact outcome you desired.

Comment: oh, sorry. my mistakes. thank u very much for your helping